# How to implement the Picker List in react native with the Parent and Child Values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

For every parent object, we have to list the child objects. And I have attached the screenshot which we have implemented on a web app.

Here is the Data structure

```
"parentValues" : [
    {
        "id" : "Apple", 
        "childValues" : [
            {
                "value" : "Iphone 5", 
                "id" : "Iphone 5"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : "Iphone 6", 
                "id" : "Iphone 6"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : "Iphone 6s", 
                "id" : "Iphone 6s"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : "Iphone 7", 
                "id" : "Iphone 7"
            }
        ]
    },
```

[image: Screenshot: implementation in web app]